# Nest.js get request header in passport local strategy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, passport.js, nestjs

How can I get the request headers inside passport local strategy?
I need a separate database for each entity, using mongodb so I need a way to get the subdomain before authentication in order to determine the database that I should connect to

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
        constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
            super({ usernameField: 'email' })
        }
    
        async validate(email: string, password: string, headers:Headers): Promise<IUser> {
            //** this is what I want to have
            //** const subdomain = headers.host.split(".")[0]
            const user = await this.authService.validateUser({ email, password ,//** subdomain})
            if (!user) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException()
            }
            return user
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add `passReqToCallback: true` to the `super` call in the constructor. This will make `req` the first parameter of the `validate` so you can do something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({ usernameField: 'email', passReqToCallback: true })
  }

  async validate(req: Request, email: string, password: string, headers:Headers): Promise<IUser> {
    const subdomain = req.headers.host.split(".")[0];
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser({ email, password ,//** subdomain})
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException()
    }
    return user
  }
}
```

Comment: How can access to ``` user ``` from the controller?

Comment: Like you would with any passport strategy. `req.user`

Comment: Thanks bro

I couldn't find the docs which this property is specified